# I would like to pop up confirmation message before deleting the data react and django?

Tags: reactjs

I am able to delete data without the confirmation message, please help me to set the confirmation in between the Axios part. code added along with this.

```
const navigate = useNavigate();
    const Delete = async () => {

        await axios({
            method: 'DELETE',
            url: `http://localhost:8000/update/${id}`,
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
            }
            

        }).then(response => {
            navigate('/')
        })
    }
```

Comment: What confirmation message are you referring to? What exactly is the issue? What are you trying to do? Can you add a more complete code example? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to confirm before delete, follow this

```
import { confirmAlert } from 'react-confirm-alert'; // Import
import 'react-confirm-alert/src/react-confirm-alert.css'; // Import css

function App() {

    const Delete = async () => {

        await axios({
            method: 'DELETE',
            url: `http://localhost:8000/update/${id}`,
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
            }
            

        }).then(response => {
            navigate('/')
        })
    }

  const submit = () => {

    confirmAlert({
      title: 'Confirm to submit',
      message: 'Are you sure to do this.',
      buttons: [
        {
          label: 'Yes',
          onClick: () => Delete()
        },
        {
          label: 'No',
          //onClick: () => alert('Click No')
        }
      ]
    });
  }

  return (
      <div className='container'>
        <button onClick={submit}>Confirm dialog</button>
      </div>
  );

}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 5):

```
let answer = window.confirm("Delete?");
```

`answer` will either be `true` or `false`. So:

```
if (window.confirm("Delete?"))
{ 
   // Here you can put your logic or function that needs to be executed as per the use case.
}
```

`window.confirm` returns a boolean, so if it's true u can proceed and if its false (which it will be once you click the Cancel button on alert), the alert dialog box will close.